# OpenGL system monitor

Tags: c++, linux, bash, opengl

I'm planning to make a graphical system monitor program on GNU/Linux similar to this one, extended with 3D elements: http://sampings.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Iron-Man-Jarvis-Computer-Wallpaper.jpg

I did some research so far and found that OpenGL would suit my needs as it would put the load on the GPU. Do you think it would be suitable for it?

Second, I have a little knowledge in C++, but I'm quite experienced in BASH. Is it possible to write GUI apps that use OpenGL for rendering in BASH? Also, I would prefer BASH as my program would access system data and therefore use shell builtins and core binaries as well like grep, awk, sed, hddtemp, uptime, cat and so on. It might be troublesome from a compiled C++ program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to write a good looking GUI such as the one you have shown, you should probably consider learning C++, especially if you plan to use OpenGL. Then you could use [CEGUI](http://cegui.org.uk/) (or similar) to create your GUI using OpenGL renderer.

I don't think BASH is a valid concurrent to C++ for this kind of applications.

Comment: Thank you, I'll go for it. Seems nice.

Comment: Great, remember to mark the answer to close the thread.